# pseudo-VoWiFi on any Android phone thru manual routing?

Tags: android, networking, routes, roaming

Let's assume I have two SIMs on Android phone.

SIM1 corresponds to roaming, the carrier supports VoLTE and VoWiFi so I can easily enjoy home pricing for calls and messages as soon as I have WiFi.
SIM2 corresponds to local provider and allows to have access to 4G internet for quite cheap price.

The task is to make SIM1 working using SIM2 internet in the places where WiFi is not available.

This approach sometimes is called as "pseudo-VoWiFi" and works on iPhones and latest Samsung phones with One UI 4.

My question: is it possible to realize such pseudo-VoWiFi on any Android phone? For instance, now I have two network interfaces:
[Current routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jOyG.jpg)

Is there any way to forcely push routes to IMS service to use rmnet0 rather than swlan0 to make VoWiFi working with mobile internet?

Any suggestions/ideas on this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It\s not a problem in fact but more a feature request. Anybody having Dual-SIM Android phone with corresponding provider can reproduce what I mean.